# PowerShell: Visual Studio Code - changes in modules are not reflected

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with PowerShell plugin for editing and debuging PowerShell scripts. As my script got too large to handle I have extraced some parts into several psm1 modules. All the files resides in the same direcory - root of the VSC workspace.

If I run the script for the first time using Ctrl+F5 all the files are compiled and the script is executed. But if I then make any modifications in the imported module files (*.psm1) these changes are not reflected and the old versions of the modules are used instead.

The only thing that helps is closing and reopening VSC. How can I configure VSC in order to rebuild/recompile changed (or all) modules in my workspace before run/debug?

Comment: `Remove-Module $moduleName -Force; Import-Module $moduleName`

Comment: I do not get the solution. I have added

    $moduleName = "./mymodule.psm1"
    Remove-Module $moduleName -Force; Import-Module $moduleName

at the beggining of my script. The result is "Remove-Module : No modules were removed. Verify that the specification of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the runspace."

Comment: Run that in the integrated shell (instead of [Mark All]+[F5]) if you want to actually reload the module

Comment: Same error in the shell

Comment: If the module is not discoverable you will need different arguments for the two: `Remove-Module mymodule -Force; Import-Module ./mymodule.psm1`

Comment: This works. But can that be achieved without modifying the code or running "Remove-module" every time the code changes manually?

Comment: You can't "re-load" the module completely without removing the previous version that's already loaded into your session, no. You might be able to configure a task in VSCode to do it, but I'm know sure how to get it to execute tasks in a specific terminal. Alternatively: click the "garbage bin" icon next to the terminal selector while in the integrated powershell terminal, then click "yes" to restart the extension + shell on the warning modal about the extension crashing. That starts you off with a new powershell session

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mathias comment I have found that adding `-force` option to `Import-Module` helps.

It look like being an issue of PowerShell rather than VS Code.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2505